# Replacing an Accordion doesn't look like an Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I think I'm missing something simple here.  Initially the accordion looks fine.  I have an Ajax call that replaces and accordion but after it's replaced, it doesn't look like an accordion.  Problem is distilled below.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzerb/5nJH7/

HTML:

```
<div id="theAcc">
    <h3><a href="#">1</a></h3>
    <div>One</div>
    <h3><a href="#">2</a></h3>
    <div>Two</div>
    <h3><a href="#">3</a></h3>
    <div>Three</div>    
</div>

​<button id="btnReplace">Replace</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#theAcc" ).accordion();
});

​$("#btnReplace").click(function() {
    $("#theAcc").html("<h3><a href='#'>A</a></h3><div>AAAA</div><h3><a href='#'>B</a></h3><div>BBBB</div><h3><a href='#'>C</a></h3><div>CCCC</div>");
});​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: You might have to call `.accordion()` on the `theAcc` element again. When you replace the html for it, you lose the additional styling `.accordion()` adds to the elements, so you have to put them back. You may want to call `.destroy()` on it before you do the HTML replacement.

Comment: @Cory, that works but I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an updated jsFiddle that has the behavior you wish to see: http://jsfiddle.net/5nJH7/5/

The updated code is:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#theAcc" ).accordion();
});

$("#btnReplace").click(function() {
    $("#theAcc")
        .accordion("destroy");
        .html("<h3><a href='#'>A</a></h3><div>AAAA</div><h3><a href='#'>B</a></h3><div>BBBB</div><h3><a href='#'>C</a></h3><div>CCCC</div>")
        .accordion();
});​
```

You see the issues because you have partially destroyed HTML elements to which the accordion is bound (click events, etc.). Tearing down the accordion before doing the replace is likely the easiest way to get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the according in another div:

```
<div id="wrapper">    
<div id="theAcc">
        <h3><a href="#">1</a></h3>
        <div>One</div>
        <h3><a href="#">2</a></h3>
        <div>Two</div>
        <h3><a href="#">3</a></h3>
        <div>Three</div>    
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btnReplace">Replace</button>​​​​​​
```

And here's your new jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#theAcc" ).accordion();
});

$("#btnReplace").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").html("<div id='theAcc'><h3><a href='#'>A</a></h3><div>AAAA</div><h3><a href='#'>B</a></h3><div>BBBB</div><h3><a href='#'>C</a></h3><div>CCCC</div></div>");        $( "#theAcc" ).accordion();
});​
```